# In Julia: BigFloat RoundFromZero Seems Strange

Tags: julia, arbitrary-precision, multiprecision

In the Julia 1.0.0 REPL I get the following behavior.  The first line is an example from the documentation
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.Rounding.RoundFromZero

```
julia> BigFloat("1.0000000000000001", 5, RoundFromZero)
1.06
```

The meaning of the 5 in the above example is not clear to me.  For example,

```
julia> BigFloat("1.01", 5, RoundFromZero)
1.06
```

It would seem that the two numbers being rounded should round to different outputs in the REPL.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is rounded from zero with `5` bits precision and in both cases this is the same value equal to `1.0625`. You can check it using e.g.:

```
julia> Float64(BigFloat("1.01", 5, RoundFromZero))
1.0625
```

or

```
julia> big(0)+BigFloat("1.01", 5, RoundFromZero)
1.0625
```

or (this is hacking and should not be done):

```
julia> x = BigFloat("1.01", 5, RoundFromZero)
1.06

julia> x.prec = 10
10

julia> x
1.0625
```

or

```
julia> Base.MPFR._string(x, 10)
"1.0625"
```

Now the reason why `1.06` is printed is that Julia rounds the output (and this is a default rounding from MPFR external library in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!